# Override advanced pricing from product with catalog price rule

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, special-price

I've create a customer group called: "Dealers", the idea is that they have in their account a 10% discount on all the store.

The problem i'm facing is that if I set a product, let's say "Product A", on sale with Special Price, from 100$ to 80$, that means a 20% discount, right? Well, the Dealer Account sees that 20%, which shouldn't.

I've deactivated the subsequent rules but what I'd like to do is for this "Dealer" Customer's Group to only have that 10% discount active, and no other discounts can override that.

Can that be done?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you apply price rule condition in admin panel ??

Comment: @MohitPatel i've set promotion price from Catalog > Products > Product A (Example) > Advanced Pricing https://prnt.sc/s1hatg <-- Here's an screenshot. 

So the thing is that the catalog rule I configured on Marketing > Catalog Price Rules > Set Rule for customer group, overrides all other pricing conditions